# Unable to retrieve events via the Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been testing reading from the Graph API with an app I'm working on for a while. I've been reading events directly from their /{id} endpoints using the Python package. When I attempted this today, however, it didn't work. The response was as follows, when attempted using the Graph API Explorer.

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXXXXXXXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "HAli25GZ3N4
"
  }
}`

The Explorer itself seems to know somehow that the object in question is an event, as the field options it gives in the left sidebar are all specific to Event objects. I'm aware you need to go through App Review to be able to read public Events, but I haven't needed to thus far. What's the issue?

I've also checked the changelogs, that state nothing breaking has occured today in that instance. One thing to note was that I was briefly demoted to Moderator of the Page I'm trying to read from. I've tried using my personal Access Token and that of the Page too.

Comment: Can you post an example of your GET request?

Comment: I don't think I can see the raw GET request, but I've at least verified that the event ID does actually take you to the event on Facebook itself and that the event is public. As tagged, I'm using the Facebook Python API for this.

Comment: _“I was briefly demoted to Moderator of the Page”_ - did you generate a new access token afterwards?

Comment: Where would I go to do that? I've been using the Graph API Explorer to get my tokens.